# Como prevenir uma modal de aparecer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3

É possível prevenir uma modal de aparecer, caso determinada condição seja atingida? Exemplo do que eu quero, mais ou menos:

```
<button id="abreModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Open Modal</button>

//aí no js...
$('#abreModal').click(function () {
   if(condicao){
        // ... previne modal de abrir
   }
});
```

Sei que se eu tirar os data-toggle e data-target, e mostrar a modal manualmente, consigo. Mas tenho vários botões assim, e não gostaria de ter que trocar todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o evento click abre o modal é bem simples de fazer é só fazer assim:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
   if(condicao){
        return false;
   }
   // Seu código para abrir o modal.
});
```

Assim se a condição for verdadeira ele não vai fazer nada, você pode colocar um alert por exemplo em cima do 'return false' para enviar uma mensagem para o usuário.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/bnLy8uvf/

Comment: Para isso, eu teria que remover todos os ```data-toggle``` e ```data-target``` dos botões e mostrar a modal manualmente, como eu disse na pergunta, tenho vários botões, e não queria fazer essa alteração em todos. Gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de simplesmente prevenir que a modal seja mostrada

Comment: Como você faz para abrir o modal?

Comment: Não faço nenhum código JS pra abrir. Só tendo os atributos nos botões a modal já abre sozinha com o click.

Comment: Se os seus botões estiverem com a classe btn e você colocar sua condição e o ruturn false vai funcionar

Comment: Não, o ```return false;``` não é o suficiente, eu já testei

Comment: Fiz este exemplo e funcionou veja: https://jsfiddle.net/bnLy8uvf/

Comment: Curiosamente, no seu funciona, mas eu troquei o Handler para ```$(document).delegate``` e parou de funcionar, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/bnLy8uvf/1/

Comment: "As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated" esta função esta depreciada para a versão 3, e estou utilizando a versão 3 neste exemplo, lembrando que, você não pode usar o mesmo id em elementos diferentes então você deve utilizar para vários botões uma classe.

Comment: Sim, sim, este foi apenas um exemplo, mas você tá certo

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma opção usando os proprios eventos do bootstrap, não tão viável, mas da pra adaptar:

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(e){
   var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
   var target = button.data('target')
   //condição
   var i = 4;
   //if
   if(i > 2){
       $(target).modal('toggle')
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```